# Unable to retrieve restored archive from AWS S3 'Invalid size value: 1g'

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, docker, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I have a 430G object that I archived to Glacier from S3 using lifecyle policies a few months ago. I'm following [Archiving Amazon S3 Data to Amazon Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/archive-s3-to-glacier/) blog, and [Transitioning to the GLACIER storage class (Object Archival)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)

> Your restored object will remain in both Glacier and S3’s Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) for the duration of the retention period.....
>   Although the objects are archived in Glacier, you can’t get to them via the Glacier APIs....Because Amazon S3 maintains the mapping between your user-defined object name and the Amazon Glacier system-defined identifier, Amazon S3 objects that are stored using the Amazon Glacier option are only accessible through the Amazon S3 API

I restored the object to S3 through the console (took about 5 hours) It says that it's available, but when I try to use the awscli to download the object I keep getting the error 'Invalid size value: 1g'

I'm trying to use the aws s3 cp command (works fine for other objects) to download to an EC2 instance. This instance has a role associated that is allowed to read/write to that S3 bucket/folder. I also checked that the ubuntu user has write permissions to where I'm trying to download the object.

```
aws --version

aws-cli/1.10.17 Python/2.7.10 Linux/4.2.0-30-generic botocore/1.4.8

aws s3 cp s3://cab-arch/Backups/160211_Archive.tar 160211_Archive.tar
```

Any help would be appreciated, I can't find any info about this particular error.

Comment: You are apparently mixing up terminology... S3 archives *objects* to glacier, and "vault" terminology is not used in that context.  If you are using `aws s3 cp` please show your command line so we can get some kind of idea whether there's something ambiguous about the invocation or whether perhaps it actually us a bug in aws-cli.

Comment: [Looks like](http://kataribe.naist.jp/aws/aws-cli/commit/346a81d08f8c0f48678739d962e29675f8488c45) it's trying to convert a human-readable size to bytes. Can't imagine why that's happening for an `aws s3 cp` command. Yes, please show the CLI command you are running.

Comment: I wrote a python script using boto3 to download the object, and that's working. I think it probably is a bug in the awscli,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was actually caused by a docker bug. The filesystem I was trying to download to had previously been mounted by a docker container. Though `docker ps` did not show any running containers,  an `fd` command showed that the container still had multiple "open" files on that filesystem. I killed docker and all was well again. [Info on this docker bug](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8693)